# Trouble with If and multiple integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to fix some code:

```
function():
    answer = int(input("Write a number"))
    if answer == 101:
         print("You found a secret!")
         do_stuff()
    elif answer >= 5 and answer <= 100 and answer >= 102:
        print("This is not a valid option!")
        function()
    else:
        continue with other inputs
```

It's specifically the elif answer >= 5 (and so forth) that isn't working properly, it just moves on to the else: other inputs and i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: When do you expect `answer` to be smaller than 100 **and** larger than 102?

Comment: A number cannot simultaneously be between 5 and 100 and also greater than 102!

Comment: I suspect you just mean `elif answer >= 5`, since the first case already ruled out `101`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's never going to be the case that

```
answer >= 5 and answer <= 100 and answer >= 102
```

! I think you may mean

```
answer >= 5 and answer <= 100 or answer >= 102
```

. Or how about:

```
5 <= answer <= 100 or 102 <= answer
```

Comment: (note difference between `and` and `or`)

Answer (score 1):

For you first elif statement, your logic is incorrect. The python and statement means that all conditions must be true in order to execute. What you wrote, however, says that answer must be greater than five, less than 100, and greater than 102. That does not make sense, as the number cannot be both greater than 100 and less than 100. What you need is an or statement:

```
elif answer >= 5 and answer <= 100 or answer >= 102:
```